Family of harmonic functions is normal if and only if family of harmonic conjugates is normal
(a) Let $u$ be a harmonic function in a simply connected region and $v$ be its conjugate. Is it true that $u$ is bounded if and only if $v$ is bounded.
(b) Assume $\mathcal{U} = \{u_n\}$ is a family of harmonic functions and $\mathcal{V}$ be family of conjugates. Is it true that $\mathcal{U}$ is normal if and only if $\mathcal{V}$ is normal.
(c) What if we impose extra condition that there is a point $z$ such that $u_n(z) = v_n(z) = 0$ for every $n$.
My attempt:
(a) This is false since we have an example of holomorphic $\log(z) = \ln|z| + i\arg(z)$ where $\arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi)$ so in particular it is bounded but $\ln|z|$ is not bounded.
(b) This is also false. Consider $\mathcal{U} = \{n\}$ and $\mathcal{V} = \{0\}$. Then $f_n(z) = n + i0 = n$ is holomorphic so $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ are harmonic, but $\mathcal{U}$ is unbounded and is not normal, while $\mathcal{V}$ is uniformly bounded and is thus normal.
(c) I am not sure how to incorporate the condition that $u_n(z) = v_n(z) = 0$ for some $z$. I also wonder whether we necessarily need that $u_n(z) = v_n(z) = 0$ or whether this can be replaced by condition that there are $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $u_n(z_1) = a$ and $v_n(z_2) = b$ for some complex numbers $a,b$.
I would appreciate any feedback and help with part (c).

Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of harmonic functions in the simply connected region $G$ which converges locally uniformly to the harmonic function $u$. Let $(v_n)$ be the corresponding sequence of harmonic conjugates normalized by $v_n(z_0) = 0$, and $v$ the harmonic conjugate of $u$ with $v(z_0) = 0$.
The functions $f_n = u_n + i v_n$ and $f=u+iv$ are holomorphic in $G$. Let $a \in G$ and $r > 0$ such that the closed disk with center $a$ and radius $2r$ is contained in $G$. By the Borel–Carathéodory theorem (with $R=2r$) is
$$
 |f_n(z) - f(z)| \le 2 \max \{ |u_n(w) - u(w)| : |w-a| \le 2r \}
 + 3 |f_n(a) - f(a)|
$$
for $|z-a| \le r$. It follows that $f_n \to f$ uniformly in $B_r(a)$, and therefore $v_n \to v$ uniformly in $B_r(a)$.
This proves that $v_n \to v$ locally uniformly in $G$.
Therefore, if $\cal U$ is a normal family of harmonic functions in $G$ and $\cal V$ the family of harmonic conjugates with $v(z_0) = 0$ then every sequence in $\cal V$ has a locally uniformly convergent subsequence, i.e. $\cal V$ is normal.
Of course the condition $v(z_0) = 0$ for all $v \in \cal V$ can be replaced by $v(z_0) = b$ for any $b \in \Bbb R$.
If even suffices that $\{ v(z_0) \mid v \in \cal V \}$ is bounded for some $z_0 \in G$. Then the Borel–Carathéodory theorem shows that the functions $f_n = u_n + v_n$ are locally uniformly bounded, so that $(f_n)$ and consequently $(v_n)$ has a local uniformly convergent subsequence.
If both $\{ u(z_0) \mid u \in \cal U \}$ and $\{ v(z_0) \mid v \in \cal V \}$ are bounded for some $z_0 \in G$ then the above argument works in both directions, and we have that $\cal U$ is normal if and only if $\cal V$ is normal.

Thank you for the answer. I just wanted to see whether I understand the argument. The Borel Caratheodory theorem gives us the bound on the ball, so in particular for any compact set K we can cover it with finitely many balls and take the maximum as the bound. Would that give us convergence of $v_n$ on the whole compact set. Also, I do not quite see where did we use the fact that $v_n(z_0)=0$.

@SparklyCape290: Because of $v_n(z_0) = v(z_0) = 0$ we have $|f_n(a) - f(a)| \to 0$ at every point $a$. Then B-C gives $v_n \to v$ uniformly on every compact set because that can be covered with finitely many disks.
